# sed command to strip a match found

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file "fruit.xml" that looks like the below:

```
FRUIT="Apples"
FRUIT="Bananas"
FRUIT="Peaches"
```

I want to use a single SED line command to find all occurrences of `NAME="` and I want strip the value between the `""` from all the matches found.

So the result should look like:

```
Apples
Bananas
Peaches
```

This is the command I am using:

```
sed 's/.*FRUIT="//' fruit.xml
```

The problem is that it leaves the last `"` at the end of the value I need. eg: `Apples"`.

Comment: is there only 1 occurences per "value" or several `FRUIT="Peaches"` could appear in the file ?

Comment: There could be several occurrences of FRUIT="Peaches"

Comment: so nearly none of the proposed solution will works because they don't take care of multi occurence but just to remove surrounding info `(FRUIT+"` and last `"` so a `| sort -u` is to add to all reply i guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just catch the group and print it back: catch everything from `"` until another `"` is found with the `()` (or `\(...\)` if you don't use the `-r` option). Then, print it back with `\1`:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*FRUIT="([^"]*)"/\1/' file
Apples
Bananas
Peaches
```

You can also use field separators with `awk`: tell `awk` that your field separators are either `FRUIT="` or `"`. This way, the desired content becomes the 2nd field.

```
$ awk -FS='FRUIT="|"' '{print $2}' file
Apples
Bananas
Peaches
```

---

To make your command work, just strip the `"` at the end of the line:

```
$ sed -e 's/.*FRUIT="//' -e 's/"$//' file
      ^^                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
      |                  replace " in the end of line with nothing
      -e to  allow you use multiple commands
```

Comment: proposition: the `[^"]` could be replaced by `.` in this case (same for `FRUIT="` by `="`) without any other specific constraint and based on the sample

Comment: Yep, both suggestions are quite helpful! I am upvoting the comments so that you are the one getting the credits :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be enough if you want to keep the leading spaces,

```
sed 's/\bFRUIT="\([^"]*\)"/\1/' fruit.xml
```

OR

```
sed 's/\bFRUIT="\|"//g' fruit.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this replaces the line with the founded fruit in the quotes:

```
sed 's/.*FRUIT="\(.*\)"/\1/' test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `cut` command

```
cut -d '"' -f2 fruits.xml
```

Output:

```
Apples
Bananas
Peaches
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming 1 occurence per value and with this format

```
sed 's/.*="//;s/".*$//' fruit.xml
```